# Azure Synapse Copy Upsert with Pipeline Parameter

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-pipeline

I am trying to Parameterize Synapse Copy **Upsert** Keys using pipeline parameters with

```
@pipeline().parameters.Upsert_Column_1
```

But I am getting following error

```
Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'writeBehaviorKeys'.
Expected type is 'Array' or 'Object'.
```

Also Can I pass list of Column names to `Upsert_Column_1` if I have more than one column ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-factory/connector-azure-synapse-analytics-copy-activity#destination

What is the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'writeBehaviorKeys'.
> Expected type is 'Array' or 'Object'

The error message indicates that the value of the parameter to be of `array` type and the value you passed is of `string` type.
You can pass more than one column names as a parameter value to the `Key columns` field of upsert copy activity. Below is the approach to do this.

- Create a parameter of type `Array`

[image]

- Add the dynamic expression `@pipeline().parameters_Upsert_Column`  in the key columns field.

[image]

- If you want to upsert the data based on the fields like,  "id" and  "WorkOrderId" , you can pass the value of parameter as `[ "id", "WorkOrderId" ]` . This is the format for the value to be passed as value to key column parameter.